# want to use two click function in one binding in knockoutJs

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, durandal

Hi folks am new to knockoutJs,i want to use two click function in one binding.I tried like below but only first part is working .if i use attr: { href: '#/User/Add/' + user_id } after click then attr will work,select user is not working n vicevirse.Help me in this regard.Am Using Durandal as a roUter

```
 <a data-bind="click: $root.SelectedUser,attr: { href: '#/User/Add/' + user_id }"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to create one function within your viewmodel, which selects user and then redirects to your desired location:

```
define(['plugins/router'], function(router){
var userIds = ['1', '2', '3'] //this is just an example. use your own ids here
var SelectedUser = ko.observable('');

var buttonClick = function(user){
    SelectedUser(user);
    router.navigate('#/User/Add/' + user);
}

return {
    userIds: userIds,
    buttonClick: buttonClick
}}
```

in your html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: userIds">
<li>
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.buttonClick"></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you want to do this?

An alternative could be to call durandal routing in your click event.

```
var clickEvent = function(data, e) {
    doSelectedUserStuff();
    callDurandalRoute('#/User/Add/' + user_id);
}
```